# error creating custom tableview separator

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I'm trying to create a tableview with custom separator. I made a custom Cell that holds the content, and another that contains only a UIImageView with the separator.
The problem is in how content is being accessed.
I can not use the indexPath.row

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"CustomCell"];
    if(cell == nil) 
    { 
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    SeparatorCell *cellSeparator = (SeparatorCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"SeparatorCell"];
    if(cellSeparator == nil) 
    { 
        cellSeparator = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SeparatorCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    if(indexPath.row % 2)
    {
        UIFont * myCustomFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Black" size:16];
        [cell.titulo setFont:myCustomFont];
        cell.titulo.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:103/255.0f green:169/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:1];

        cell.titulo.text = [Title objectAtIndex:myRow];
        cell.subtitle.text = [Subtitle objectAtIndex:myRow];

        cell.tag = myRow;
        myRow++;
    }
    else [cellSeparator.imagem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CustomSeparator.png"]];

    if(indexPath.row % 2) return cell;
    else return cellSeparator;
}
```

> myRow

is a global NSInteger.

I already tried

```
if(myRow == Title.count) myRow=0;
        else myRow++;
```

Comment: What happens when you use it?

Comment: I go down in the tableview, and a row disappear, when i go back to see that row again,Xcode gives me an error, trying to access an object in the array that does not exist, I believe that the variable >myRow 
was not reset.

Comment: Instead of using the variable `myRow`, why don't you just use `indexPath.row%2`?

Comment: indexPath.row alone is not enough,just as @Eyal said the answer is indexPath.row/2.

Comment: oops that's what I meant

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSInteger numOfRowsIncludeSeparator = 0;

    if (self.model.count > 0) {
        NSInteger numOfSeperators = self.model.count - 1;
        numOfRowsIncludeSeparator = self.model.count + numOfSeperators;
    }
    return numOfRowsIncludeSeparator;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *ContentCellIdentifier = @"ContentCell";
    static NSString *SeparatorCellIdentifier = @"SeparatorCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        // this is a content cell
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ContentCellIdentifier];

        if(cell == nil) 
        { 
            cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContentCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        // get the model index
        NSInteger indexInModel = indexPath.row / 2;

        // get the model for this row
        NSString *modelObject = [self.model objectAtIndex:indexInModel];

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel.text = modelObject;
    }
    else {
        // this is a separator cell
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SeparatorCellIdentifier];

        if(cell == nil) 
        { 
            cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SeparatorCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Don't forget to set the `Identifier` field in IB of the ContentCell.xib to be "ContentCell" and the SeparatorCell.xib to be "SeparatorCell".