# Adding space between UITableView cells and making them round cornered

Tags: ios

I have a UItableView in which I am loading RSS. I would like to leave a space between each cell in the table view, as well as giving round corners to each cell, to give an effect like this one:

[image]

The problem is that I can't seem to find working code. Using:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 10.; // you can have your own choice, of course
}
```

only adds space on top of the UITableView...

Comment: Same question as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189523/how-to-give-space-between-two-cells-in-tableview

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to create this UI is to create a custom `UITableViewCell` that will have that extra space at bottom, if you can create a .png file that will be the gray background with the rounded corners or you can round the corners with `view.layer.cornerRadius` (don't forget to include `QuartzCore` for cornerRadius), add a label and an arrow and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

No need to customize anything.

You have to initialize your tableView with a "groupedStyle". Or, if you you're using storyboard, set the style there. Then make the tableView background color to whatever you want.

```
myTableViewContoller = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

the heightForHeaderInSection thing is for sections, not rows.
you can do heightForRowAtIndexPath if you really need to for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can first make cells to be clear color background, then add a rounded corner view which should be smaller than the cell. This makes it looks like it gets a spacing around the cell.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older one, but I ran into this problem recently.  If your cells have a custom uiTableViewCell class add this to the bottom of the .m file of the class (just above @end)

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    frame.origin.y += 4;
    frame.size.height -= 2 * 5;  //adds the space and gives a 5 point buffer, can also indent the width using frame.size.width
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```