# How to create padding(spacing) between rows in tablview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This isn't a duplicate I read the other questions regarding this and none of them gave me what i needed , I'm creating a table view with custom cell and the style is grouped. I have 1 ImageView inside each row that is smaller then the whole row.How many cells I need to create is somthing i get from the db so I cant use static cells I need to have spacing between the rows,I cant figure out how to do this. I tried making the cell Bigger (320,143) and making it invisible which i managed to do but then when you press outside the image it still acting like i pressed the cell 
this is pretty much what i want to achieve

[image: first pic]

but this is what happens:

[image: second pic]

I need the cell to be the images size but to have spacing between diffrent rows. how can i do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Many ways to do it, but I found this is the simplest and easiest way to do so.

Set `UITableView` style grouped. Then have two sections and each section has only one row. Replace your image in the row.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    //array is your db, here we just need how many they are
    return [array count];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 1;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //place your image to cell
}
- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    //this is the space
    return 50;
}
```

Comment: my UITableview style is already grouped, I dont have only 2 images to show , how many I have is something i store in the db , and what do you mean by sectors?

Comment: did you mean to create static cells and use sections? I cant do that because I cant know how many cells i will need

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I mean sections not sectors. I updated answer. This should solve your problem.

Comment: this works but now i've got one problem. this is the code I use to create the image inside each cell:    GameTypeItem *item = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  and now each one of the cells contains the first picture(Movies) how can i get the number of the section I'm in? I mean insted of indexPath.row i need something like tableView.sections.currentSectionNumber

Comment: Change "GameTypeItem *item = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];" to GameTypeItem *item = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

Comment: This is easiest way,I found so far,but if you need to use sections and rows and avoid overload of extra ones,try adding elements on UIView,instead directly in content view.Also,add constraints accordingly.

Comment: Here is the padding between sections are created, not between rows, so, it does not answer to the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in just 3 lines.

First set gray color of your main view after that follow these lines.

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20);
cell.layer.borderWidth = 5;
cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply make the content of your cell clearcolor and give yourself padding by adding height. Add the background image (or color) of your cell however you'd like afterwards by inserting a new view or label of shorter height.

This way you can maintain a table with multiple sections and multiple rows.

Answer (score 2):

1.First you can Increase heightForRowAtIndexPath  size

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 150;
}
```

2. Then add custom view on `tableViewCell`. then set view.frame according padding you want.

Answer (score 0):

in swift 5.1 :

```
   override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return 2
   }
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return 1
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
       return 15
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
       return 30
   }
```