# Disable part of Cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to disable part of the `UITableView` `cell`.  Please see image below.
This white part is a `view` in my `cell`. I don't know how to disable it, so that when user taps it nothing will happen. Maybe some king of mask?

[image]

Comment: are you providing some action to that view on tap?

Comment: what do you want to disable?

Comment: You can hide your view by setting its hidden property to YES. IS this what you are looking for?

Comment: If you mean you want some inactive padding between your cells, I would try making each cell its own section and using (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section to set the padding for each section. Will be much cleaner than what you're doing.

Comment: @Chase Ok.Thank you. Will do like you suggest

Comment: @T_77 I don't want to hide view, I want to disable it

Comment: If the white part of your cell is an UIView, you can add a tapGestureRecognizer to it and leave the implementation of the action selector empty.

Comment: @Chase I changed my rows to sections, but cant set `self.tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 25;` - it does nothing...

Comment: @Edgar take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490203/how-to-create-paddingspacing-between-rows-in-tablview The footer height is set in a delegate method not as a property just like the row height is set

Comment: thank you, but also nothing. + error msg: _conflicting return type in implementation of 'tableView:heightForFooterInSection:': 'CGFloat' (aka 'double') vs 'float'_

Comment: Ah yes it looks like it is a CGFloat. Return your value as a CGfloat. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForFooterInSection:

Comment: @Edgar In addition, the method won't be called unless you change your tablView style to UITableViewStyleGrouped

Comment: @Chase Thank you for help! I managed to change height, but now something strange is happening.. footer sticked to the bottom of the screen...  http://imgur.com/Qw8vXSy

Comment: @Edgar can you include all your delegate methods for me. I want to see how you're setting up the cells. You don't want that white space right? The first cell looks good but the second cell seems messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving this out of the comments section. If you want padding between your cells what you should do is make each row its own section and use the delegate method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

However, this method will not be called if your tableview is the default style. So, set your tableview style to `UITableViewStyleGrouped`

Then you have to implement the delegate methods so that you return a height for the footer and make sure that each row gets its own section:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    //Return however many rows you have specifically or the count of the datasource
    return [array count];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    CGFloat myHeight = 50.0 //your height here
    return myHeight;
}
```

Implementing these three delegate methods like this should add a nice transparent padding between your cells.

Comment: Thank you for help! This was because of `UITableViewStyle` not being set to `Grouped`

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple approach.Place a button on top of custom table view cell to mask the area which you want to be un-clickable. This acts as a mask on top of tableview cell which stops calling row did select delegate method. If you want to add any action for button click event add a method to button by passing row index.