# xcode 8 swift 3 UItableview space between cells?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

i am trying to make space between cells in `UItableview` i've checked google all posts i found is more than 3 years old , when i try to apply them i am getting so many errors, is it possible to make space between cells in `UItableview` ?

**my Code :**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ImageCell") as! ImageCell
    cell.model = self.modelAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    let url = URL(string: cell.model.imageName)
    cell.imgBack.kf.setImage(with: url)

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    //send back playlist count
    if (section == 0) {
        return self.lists_arr.count
    }
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated:true)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let imageCell = cell as! ImageCell
    self.setCellImageOffset(imageCell, indexPath: indexPath)
}

//number of sections in table
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func modelAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> CellPlaylist {
    return self.lists_arr[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row % self.lists_arr.count]
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (scrollView == self.tblMain) {
        for indexPath in self.tblMain.indexPathsForVisibleRows! {
            if let imgCel : ImageCell = self.tblMain.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ImageCell {
             self.setCellImageOffset(imgCel, indexPath: indexPath)
            }
        }
    }
}

func setCellImageOffset(_ cell: ImageCell, indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cellFrame = self.tblMain.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
    let cellFrameInTable = self.tblMain.convert(cellFrame, to:self.tblMain.superview)
    let cellOffset = cellFrameInTable.origin.y + cellFrameInTable.size.height
    let tableHeight = self.tblMain.bounds.size.height + cellFrameInTable.size.height
    let cellOffsetFactor = cellOffset / tableHeight
    cell.setBackgroundOffset(cellOffsetFactor)

}
```

**The class of TableCell :**

```
class ImageCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgBack: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgBackTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgBackBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    let imageParallaxFactor: CGFloat = 70

    var imgBackTopInitial: CGFloat!
    var imgBackBottomInitial: CGFloat!


    var model: CellPlaylist! {
        didSet {
            self.updateView()
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.imgBackBottomConstraint.constant -= 2 * imageParallaxFactor
        self.imgBackTopInitial = self.imgBackTopConstraint.constant
        self.imgBackBottomInitial = self.imgBackBottomConstraint.constant
    }

    func updateView() {
       // self.imgBack.imageFromServerURL(urlString: self.model.imageName)
        //self.getImage(url: self.model.imageName,imgView: self.imgBack)
        //self.model.imageName
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 3
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 8, height: 8)).cgPath
      self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
     self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

        self.contentView.layoutMargins.top = 20

        self.lblTitle.text = self.model.title
    }

    func setBackgroundOffset(_ offset:CGFloat) {
        let boundOffset = max(0, min(1, offset))
        let pixelOffset = (1-boundOffset)*2*imageParallaxFactor
        self.imgBackTopConstraint.constant = self.imgBackTopInitial - pixelOffset
        self.imgBackBottomConstraint.constant = self.imgBackBottomInitial + pixelOffset
    }



}
```

**The storyboard :**

[image]

> what i am getting

:

[image]

> what i want :

[image]

Comment: change the frame of  `view` inside the `contentView` of `UITableCell`

Comment: have every cell be a part of a separate section. And give every section a transparent footerView. Or create a view inside your cell and have the cell contentView be transparent. The created view will have a bottom constraint to the contentView that has the required spacing. Can't give a fully fledged answer cause I'm on my way from work. If you couldn't work it out mention it and I'll see about helping you later

Comment: @Dhiru i did so still no spacing

Comment: @DatForis :) thanks i will be waiting for you full reply

Comment: Look at : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17490283/833885

Comment: @JackKFouani - don't use same size as to `contentView` make the `view`  give margin from all sides than use `autoLayout` so that this `view` will maintain the margin from all size (take constraints from all four sides ) 
......than use `view.clipsToBound=YES` .... you can also change this property from  storyBoard

Comment: deisgn your cells in a way that they contain that white space like @Jignesh Mayani answerd. Or create sections.

Comment: Just add sections and keep number of rows one. give space between sections thats it.  rest of your code is correct.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Make Tablview BG colour white and set BG View colour in cell that you want to keep see in image i have set bgview  BG colour is light greay and make BGview hight smaller then cell i mean if you want to set space 10 pixel keep Bg hight smaller then cell 10 pixel

Here is my cell
[image]
And here is out put

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this.  Way better than adding sections.

Answer (score 12):

Update: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect method is replaced now you can do it like this

```
contentView.frame = contentView.frame.inset(by: margins)
```

Swift 4 answer:

in your custom cell class add this function

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    //set the values for top,left,bottom,right margins
    let margins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    contentView.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(contentView.frame, margins)
}
```

You can change values as per your need

Comment: Old way of setting insets - outdated

Comment: @cfl what is the new way?

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz When I typed it in Xcode, it was shown as obsolete. I haven't figured out the solution yet

Comment: I would be thankful if you share the updated method of doing. I have done some research but haven't found any better

Answer (score 9):

You can let every cell to take a section in group tableView, then you set the section's footer.

Try my code:

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "VC1Cell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "VC1Cell")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: -- tableview delegate

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let view:UIView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 10))
        view.backgroundColor = .clear

        return view
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 44
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:VC1Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VC1Cell") as! VC1Cell
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10.0
    }


}
```

The result:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: But u have 10 sections in this realization. It's a workaround, use layout inside cell.

Comment: @LoraKucher using layout inside cell is also workaround

Answer (score 9):

### Swift 4.2 solution

Inside UITableViewCell subclass

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    bounds = bounds.inset(by: padding)
}
```

### Swift 5.0 solution

Inside UITableViewCell subclass

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    bounds = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Building on Gulfam Khan's answer, the new way of setting the inset:

Swift 4:

```
 override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        //set the values for top,left,bottom,right margins
        let margins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
        contentView.frame = contentView.frame.inset(by: margins)
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    contentView.frame = contentView.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5.2 Solution**

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    bounds = bounds.inset(by: padding)
}
```