# Variable space between cells within the same section

Tags: ios, swift

## The situation:

I have a chat view. It's similar to whatsapp where different days have a little header showing the date. I did that by making a section for each separate date and showing the date in the section header.

Cells show the name of the sender if the previous message was from a different sender. So if

- Message 1 is from Alice
- Messages 2 and 3 are from Bob
- Messages 4 and 5 are from Alice

then messages 1, 2 and 4 will show the sender name. This was easy enough by just setting a bool on the message model in the mapping process after fetching them from the api. The cell checks for this bool and either sets or doesn't set the sender name label text.

I have to change the space between cells depending on this too. If a cell doesn't show the sender name, e.g. it is from the same sender as the previous message, it should have less margin between itself and the previous message. If the cell is the topmost cell in the section the margin should remain as is.

I tried overriding `layoutSubviews` like this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    bounds = bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
}
```

Where `topInset` is a CGFloat that I set in the cell dequeue like this:

```
cell.topInset = item.isSenderSameAsPrevious && indexPath.row > 0 ? 10 : 0
```

Where `item` is my message model.

## The problem:

Message 1 has a sender name and a default margin to its top (the section header), message 2 is from the same sender and doesn't have a sender name and a smaller margin to its top (message 1).
However, message 3 is also from the same sender, it doesn't have the sender name (so I know the bool is set correctly) but it has a default margin to its top (message 2).

I'm assuming that setting the inset like I did (which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53324309/11312049)) is not working as intended because it simply shifts the cell's contentView up. What I need is that each subsequent message from the same sender has a small margin to its predecessor until a message from a different sender comes in between or a message is on a different day.

**What would be the best way to set the space between two cells, depending on an arbitrary check for each cell?**

Answer (score 1):

**UICollectionView solution**

This might be a bigger change than what you are looking for, but I would definitely use collectionView for this, so you get access to interim spacing and section spacing. If I understand UITableView, it has no spacing for items

*Now put the consecutive messages from the same participant to the same section, and open a new section for the next group (consecutive messages from the other participant)*. Subclass the FlowLayoutDelegation and override `minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt` and `minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt`. Quick and simple without needing to write a layout.

If you decide to do that I can give you more details.

**UITableView solution**

One more option for TableView. Have your normal cell insets and padding set to whatever you need for messages from same user in one section, and make the "invisible" header bigger that will separate the groups. You still need the sections.

Comment: After discussing with a coworker we came up with a constraint based solution. See my answer. Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: Great to hear! You might add your solution under your question, someone might find it very useful later.

Answer (score 0):

I went with the following approach:

The cell's class has an `IBOutlet` for the top constraint. The xib binds the cell's top constraint to the outlet. In the class I have a setter to set the top constraint to a smaller value than its default. From `dequeuecell` where I have access to the model's bool I make a call to this setter to set the top margin accordingly.

This works for me because the cells already have some default spacing on all sides. I can simply negate the spacing on the top side to make it seem like this cell is closer to its predecessor.