# How to add space between tableView cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to add space between a `UITableViewCell`. Where do i need to provide anchoring for space?

[image]

Comment: Please check the link below:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43849297/xcode-8-swift-3-uitableview-space-between-cells/43849873

Answer (score 8):

You can use one of these ways:

**First way:** Change frame of the `contentView` of your TableViewCell. Override `layoutSubviews` method in your TableViewCell like this:

```
 override func layoutSubviews() {
      super.layoutSubviews()
      let bottomSpace: CGFloat = 10.0 // Let's assume the space you want is 10
      self.contentView.frame = self.contentView.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: bottomSpace, right: 0))
 }
```

**Second way:** Change your UITableView Datasource and Delegate: number of sections in your tableview will be the same as your items count, with one item in each section. And there is one footer view for each section (with height is equal to the space you want to), dont forget to set background color of the footer view if needed.