# Adding space between cells in a section in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, spacing, uitableview, cellpadding

I need to add padding so space between each cell in each section in swift 2.1

but all I managed to do was adding header for section which I don't want that.

how can I add space between dynamic table cells?

Here is the code for adding header:

```
    // Set the spacing between sections
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let header = UIView()
        header.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        return header
    }
```

Here is creating table view code:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.tableData.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {

    //Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let rowData = self.tableData[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel!.text = rowData.name
    cell.textLabel!.textAlignment = .Right


    if let url  = NSURL(string: rowData.img),
        data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
    {
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data)
    }



    return cell
    }
```

Right now my table view look like this:

[image]

update code and table view :

[image]

Comment: Where exactly should be the space? Between every cell?

Comment: You want to increase space between two cell?

Comment: @ChikabuZ i want to add space between two cell

Comment: @MehulSojitra yes i need to add space between two cell

Comment: Use tableview's delegate method heightForRowAtIndexPath which will return height of cell.

Comment: @MehulSojitra ok but what should i do with that height ?

Comment: Just set the height you want.

Comment: Default height of cell is 44px. you can set custom height of table cell using that method only by returning float value see below ChikabuZ's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just set cell height:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
   return 100 //cell height
}
```

UPDATE:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
   if indexPath.row % 2 == 0
   {
      return 100 //cell height
   }
   else
   {
      return 5 //space heigh
   }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {

    //Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0
    {
        let rowData = self.tableData[indexPath.row/2]

        cell.textLabel!.text = rowData.name
        cell.textLabel!.textAlignment = .Right

        if let url  = NSURL(string: rowData.img),
            data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
        {
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
        else
        {
            cell.imageView?.image = nil
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel!.text = nil
        cell.imageView?.image = nil
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: your method just changes the height of cells ! not adding padding to them!

Comment: Thanks. updated method worked. but there is bit problem which the space between cells is filled by texts ! and made it ugly any idea how to fix it ? i've put the new table view screenshot in the post above

Comment: You should set cell.textLabel!.text = nil and cell.imageView?.image = nil if it space cell.

Comment: you mean i put this two lines in else block : cell.textLabel!.text = nil
            cell.imageView?.image = nil ... sorry i'm still new to swift !

Comment: but the problem here is that i need to write " index let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)"        line first to make cell readable! and it's not possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99808/discussion-between-anonymox-and-chikabuz).

Comment: i need your help, i can not figure it out how to stop reusing cells! please help me out!

Comment: updated, don't forget get right value from data: let rowData = self.tableData[indexPath.row/2]

Comment: and self.tableData.count * 2 in numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: Thank you again. I almost forgot that.

Answer (score 6):

There is no spacing between cells in a table view. Only in a collection view.

The options available to you are...

1. Use a collection view instead. It's relatively easy to make it look like a table view. Using this you can use the inter item spacing.
2. Increase the height of the cells by 2 pixels and add a blank area to the top or bottom of each. This will give the illusion of adding space between them.

Comment: thanks for answer, but how can i achieve the second method ?

Comment: @anonymox if you have a height of 100 currently. Then just change it to 102. But keep all your views how they are. So the image will still go from 0 (top) to 100 (bottom). So it will have a gap of 2 at the bottom to the edge of the cell.

Comment: i've done what you said but just the height of cells is changed to 102. and all of content are still close to each other. plz be aware that my table view is creating contents dynamically

Comment: @anonymox yes, you are probably using AutoLayout to create the cells. You need to update the contents to make the gap at the bottom so that the content doesn't just grow to fit into the new height.

Comment: i've set the cell height to 105 and height of content to 40 but still they don't get space in between. can i use sections to show my content instead of cells ?

Comment: @anonymox Are you using auto layout? Is it in a storyboard? You haven't shown anywhere how you are actually creating the content and the layout. If you are using auto layout then you should be able to set the "vertical gap" between the image bottom and the cell bottom to 5 and have a gap of 5. Without knowing how you are creating the content it's hard to debug anything.

Comment: yes i'm using storyboard and auto layout. but my prototype cell is empty. and it's content created from the code above! actually the content come from xml rss feed which I parse it and send it to table view

Comment: @Fogmeister what if the cell you are using has a border color and border width and you want there to be space in between the bottom of one cell and the top of the next. If that's the case, would switching to a collection view be the only option?

Comment: @PatNeedham you could still do it with a table view. Just use a UIView inside your cells. Of course, you're now getting to a scenario where a collection view would make it much easier so maybe it would be better to switch.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use the HeightForRowAtIndexPath or change the "row height" in your tableView Xib under the size Inspector...

Or you can check this link for objective-c:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14726457/4489420... In this it will create sections based on your array count...

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to increase the height

1. in storyboard select you you tableview and set the rowHeight(which better suites you implementation) in **size inspector**
2. Add this function in your viewController

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat 
    { return 35;//Whatever height you want...}
   ```

Comment: thans for response but it's not working for me. i need something like padding not changing height of cells ! because my contents are generated dynamically

Comment: One way to do it in the storyboard, autolayout... add top and/or bottom constraints to supper view for your imageView..

Answer (score 0):

Check this one if you are using Dynamic Heights... https://www.facebook.com/iOSApplicationDevelopers/posts/1297809426911662

Answer (score 0):

**Table view cells** are contiguous by design: There is no "space" between two consecutive cells; only the 1 point thick separator line (which you can do away with).

- You **can** add "padding" ( = *internal* space) inside each cell (i.e., make them taller - see other answers), but
- You **can not** add "margin" ( = *external* space) between them (that would give you two separators between each cell, perhaps...?).

---

**Collection view cells**, on the other hand, *do* allow for extra space between cells.

Comment: thanks for participating but how can i add padding to table view cells programmatically ?

Comment: Like others mentioned, use `heightForRowAtIndexPath()` and return the total height that you want (content + padding).